# How to determine IBM cloud capacity

Tags: ibm-cloud

How can we determine the available capacity in an IBM Cloud Data Center or Regioin ?  EG how many free bare metal servers, VSIs, subnets, VLANs , etc are available in the Dallas13 Data center ?

Answer (score 0):

According to IBM cloud support, 'there is not really a public facing document that shows the DC availability. VLAN and subnets are on a case by case review, the default is no more than 5 VLANs per router and IP limitations depend on utilization. '